# 2006 Opel Vectra 2.2 direct (Z22YH) CEL and DTC P0420

Tags: engine, troubleshooting, opel, gm

Check engine light comes on in my 2006 Opel (Vauxhall, Holden, Chevy) Vectra 2.2 direct (Z22YH) with 220,000 km (140,000 mi) on it.

Car Scanner Pro app reads DTC P0420 from the ECU:

```
P0420 [0x0420]
Catalytic converter system, bank 1 - efficiency below threshold
Additional General Electrical Failures: below minimum threshold [0x12]
Status: DTC supported by calibration, Current DTC, Test not passed since DTC cleared,
Test failed since DTC cleared, History DTC, Test not passed since current power up,
Current DTC since power up, Warning Indicator Requested
```

Car Scanner Pro app reports the “catalyst monitor bank 1 – MID$21” failing:

[image: Car Scanner Pro Noncontinuous monitors screenshot]

In the “emission test” view, Car Scanner Pro reports the catalyst test as passed.

Once DTCs are cleared, it takes about 2 or 3 weeks until CEL lights up and same DTC is stored again.

The very first time this issue occurred, it came along with one cylinder misfiring. The misfiring very likely was caused by a bad spark plug. Back then, the car has been driven for a few kilometers at low speeds with the engine running rough. Spark plugs have been replaced since then.

Ever since when the CEL came on the engine was running fine about that time.

Many parts have been replaced recently before this issue has occurred (good quality parts used, installed properly):

- Coil pack
- Timing chains
- Upstream and downstream O2 sensors
- Catalyst
- Valve stem seals
- Fuel injector valves tested and found to be good (not replaced)

There is no indication of a vaccuum leak. O2 sensors readings and STFT/LTFT look reasonable to me.

Questions:

1. Can the catalyst monitor sensitivity be adjusted given the right tools at hand? I am wondering if todays's catalysts are “more optimized” (in terms of the amount of precious metals used) than 20 years ago and if the ECU threshold values are a tad too strict now.
2. Did driving the car with the engine running rough brick the new catalyst?
3. What are other potential causes and remedies?